# About Apache httpd.conf and application sever aaa.conf port 80 and 443

Tags: apache, app-config, httpd.conf

This question is about httpd.conf and aaa.conf file configuration.

```
 Listen 443
 <VirtualHost  aaa.xyz.com:80>
 ServerName ------.xyz.com
 DocumentRoot "--------------"
```

### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost  aaa.xyz.com:443>
ServerName    aaa.xyz.com
ServerAlias   aaa
------------------------------------
Proxy Pass   // aaa.xyz.com:1000/fff
Proxy Reverse // aaa.xyz.com:1000/fff
```

### aaa.conf

I would like to ask what are these ports 80 and 443 referring to? Is it when a client requests for the webpage, the request is sent to port 443 httpd.conf. From there it listens and then goes over to aaa.conf to look for the requested webpage. If the webpage exists, it gets extracted out and sent to port 80 of httpd.conf. Then, the requested being carried on port 80 is being sent to the client and it is then displayed on the client's browser?

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  First of all there are many things wrong with that configuration.
Lets fix that first:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DebugLevel error
    ErrorLog "logs/80_error_log"
    AccessLog "logs/80_access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot "/SOMEDIRECTORY"
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DebugLevel error
    ErrorLog "logs/443_error_log"
    AccessLog "logs/443_access_log" combined

    # SSL CERTIFICATES CONFIGURATION HERE

    ProxyPass        "/" "http://aaa.xyz.com:1000/fff"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://aaa.zyx.com:1000/fff"
</VirtualHost>
```

This assumes that you have loaded modules:

- mod_proxy
- mod_proxy_http
- mod_ssl

**About the ports**

A port is used to open connections to a server, and then talk to it.  How you talk to it must match between the client and the server.  It was decided that port 80 would be used to do http, and port 443 to do https.  If you send some other traffic to these ports, Apache will not know what to do with it, since it is expecting HTTP(s) requests.

**The client goes to `http://www.example.com` or `http://example.com`**

The first VirtualHost is used, since the domain and port match (http port is
80 by default).  The requested webpage is taken from the `DocumentRoot` directory.

**The client goes to `https://www.example.com` or `https://example.com`**

The second VirtualHost is used, since the domain and port matches (https port is
443 by default).

Then the proxy configurationn:

- Apache "becomes a client" and sends the request over to `http://aaa.xyz.com:1000/fff` and waits for the response, as a browser would do.
- When the response is received by Apache, it removes references to `aaa.xyz.com` in the answer files and sends those to the client's browser.
- in essence, Apache hides `aaa.xyz.com`, so from the client's browser perspective, all requests still go to - and from - `www.example.com`.

I suggest you read https://www.guru99.com/apache.html then 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html